# Option clash for \usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}

Tags: packages

In my preambule; I put `\usepackage[enableskew]{young}`
and `\usepackage[enableskew]{upgreek}`.

The compiler says `Option clash for package youngtab.`

Sometimes the compiler do not say anything sometimes it does.

What can I do?

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
% \documentclass[a4paper,openany,11pt]{book}
% OPENANY ?
%\usepackage[greek,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel}
\setlength{\textwidth}{410pt} %AJOUTE avec ukon MANIPULER LES                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{stmaryrd }
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lmodern}% remplacer   ventuellement par txfonts,           
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{ gensymb }
\usepackage{latexsym}
%                http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex        /contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf
\usepackage[enableskew]{young}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}
\usepackage[enableskew]{upgreek}
%TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{empheq}%PETIT SYSTEME
```

Comment: this is unrelated to texshop which is just the editor you used to write the file.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't load packages multiple times - especially not with different options**

This is the main problem and prevents the compilation of your document. To be precise, loading first `\usepackage{youngtab}` [without options] and later `\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}` will cause an option clash.

---

Besides this, your code produces a couple of warnings of the form `Unknown option enableskew for package...`. They are caused as these packages don't have the option `enableskew`. As it makes little sense to pass non-existing options to a package, remove them.

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
% \documentclass[a4paper,openany,11pt]{book}
% OPENANY ?
%\usepackage[greek,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel}
\setlength{\textwidth}{410pt} %AJOUTE avec ukon MANIPULER LES                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{stmaryrd }
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lmodern}% remplacer   ventuellement par txfonts,           
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{ gensymb }
\usepackage{latexsym}
%                http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex        /contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf
\usepackage{young}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}
\usepackage{upgreek}
%TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{empheq}%PETIT SYSTEME


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```